# getElementByClassName not working with rotateY

Tags: javascript

I've been working on this for a day. Looping thru an array of ids didn't work. queryAllSelectors didn't work. In both scenarios only the third of three divs is affected. I would love to get ByClassName work.

```
<header>
    <div onmouseover="rotateYDIV()" class="rotate3D">Thing A</div>
    <div onmouseover="rotateYDIV()" class="rotate3D">Thing B</div>
    <div onmouseover="rotateYDIV()" class="rotate3D">Thing C</div>
</header>

header {
    text-align: center;
}

div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: gray;
    display: inline-block;
}



var y,n=0,ny=0,rotINT,rotYINT

function rotateYDIV()
{
    y=document.getElementsByClassName("rotate3D");
    clearInterval(rotYINT)
    rotYINT=setInterval("startYRotate()",1)
}

function startYRotate()
{
    ny=ny+1
    y.style.transform="rotateY(" + ny + "deg)"
    y.style.webkitTransform="rotateY(" + ny + "deg)"
    y.style.OTransform="rotateY(" + ny + "deg)"
    y.style.MozTransform="rotateY(" + ny + "deg)"
    if (ny==180 || ny>=360)
        {
        clearInterval(rotYINT)
        if (ny>=360){ny=0}
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between an element and a collection of elements?

Comment: `getElementByClassName` will return a list of elements. You have to iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

getElementByClassName returns an array.  You have to loop through its elements.

```
function startYRotate()
{
    ny=ny+1
    for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
    {


        y[i].style.transform="rotateY(" + ny + "deg)"
        y[i].style.webkitTransform="rotateY(" + ny + "deg)"
        y[i].style.OTransform="rotateY(" + ny + "deg)"
        y[i].style.MozTransform="rotateY(" + ny + "deg)"
        if (ny==180 || ny>=360)
            {
            clearInterval(rotYINT)
            if (ny>=360){ny=0}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The function is not called `getClassByName`, and it does not return an array.

Comment: Why is the `ny` logic inside of your loop?

Comment: mistake...moved it out of the loop...and i had the function name wrong that's represented above

Comment: The function is not called `getElementByClassName`, and it does not return an array.

Comment: Why is half of the `ny` logic inside of your loop?

Comment: Thanks Ctznkane525. This works great for trigger every element in the array. I would like to trigger only the element hovered.